# Parse string in sh file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

For a gitlab ci/cd project, I need to find the url of a knative service (used to deploy a webservice) so that I can utilize it as my base url for load testing

I have found that I can find the url (and other information) with the command: kubectl get ksvc helloworld-go, which outputs:

```
NAME            URL                                                LATESTCREATED         LATESTREADY           READY   REASON
helloworld-go   http://helloworld-go.default.34.83.80.117.xip.io   helloworld-go-96dtk   helloworld-go-96dtk   True
```

Can someone please provide me an easy way to extract only the url in a sh script? I believe the easiest way might be to find the text between the first and second space on the second line.

Comment: Assuming the message is in file.txt: `grep "http://" file.txt | awk '{print $2}'`.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts which you have out in order to solve your own problems and let us know then.

Comment: If you use grep and awk, then you're probably doing it wrong, but that's just me. `awk 'NR>1{print $2}' file.txt ` or `awk '/http/{print $2}' file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl get ksvc helloworld-go | grep -oP "http://[^\t]*"
```

or

```
kubectl get ksvc helloworld-go | grep -Eo "http://[^[:space:]]*"
```